# Close all MDI child windows using Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, mdichild, mdiparent

I'm trying to use the following loop

```
foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
{
    frm.Close();
}
```

and transcribe it into a Linq expression like so:

```
this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.OfType<Form>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Close());
```

but this line shows me a `NullReferenceException` "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

What am I doing wrong? I am a newbie in Linq.

Comment: Which object is giving you a nullreferenceexception?

Comment: Although it saves a line (or three), I would go for the non Linq variant because it's more easy to understand.

Comment: This generally isn't the type of thing you should use LINQ for. It's more ubiquitous and readable in the foreach form.

Comment: There is no advantage in using LINQ to do this because each command must be executed in sequence. You can't benefit from any parallelization. Yeah, and then there's the fact that it's unreadable.

Comment: thanks for your comments, but affects the performance? and yes it would be to save some lines. since I mentioned previously, also I am learning to use linq (newbie), I'm in process of understanding it!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.MdiChildren.OfType<Form>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Close());
```

Unless you are trying that code from one of the children, in which case you try your code

```
this.MdiParent.MdiChildren.OfType<Form>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Close());
```

and it should also work.

Comment: tnx it works!! I´m trying to close all windows, that´s be useful